# My id of an hyperlink tag keeps displaying as text on the browser in Svelte

Tags: javascript, html, rest, svelte, sveltekit

I've been trying to make a web app wiki using my knowledge of Restful APIs and svelte and I've come across a problem where I gave the hyperlink tags the id of the id of each object in the db, it works but the problem is that it keeps on displaying the id of the hyperlink tag() as text in the browser. How can I fix this?

Here is a visual representation of the result:

[image: Here is a visual representation of the result]

Here's the code:

```
<script>
import { onMount } from 'svelte';
import { each } from 'svelte/internal';
import { store } from '$lib/store';

let articles = [];
onMount(async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/articles');
    const data = await response.json();
    articles = data;
})

</script>

<div class="container">
    {#each articles as article}
        <a href="/articles/article/{article._id}" id={article._id}>
             {article.title}
            <hr>
        </a>
        {$store = article._id}
    {/each}
</div>

<style>
    a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: rgb(223, 209, 209);
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }

    a::hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    div {
        margin-top: 90px;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
```

I really need help T_T

Comment: I'd guess you need quotes around the text in `id` for "id={article._id}" like you have for `href`.

Comment: Not terribly familiar with Svelte's stynax, but looks like you're just outputting the resulting value here `{$store = article._id}`.

Comment: Quotes usually aren't required on attributes.  What's the value of the property?

Comment: Could it be that the variable $store isn't declared so that instead of the assignment happening, the article.id is displayed? Notice that the IDs appear after the link, as shown by the last ID being on it's own line and the first line not having an ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To not display the ID, you need to remove this line:

```
{$store = article._id}
```

This is assigning to the store and returning the value, which renders the ID text. This isn't something that's normal to do in Svelte code. Usually, you update the data in your script block and render it in your template -- your template shouldn't have side effects on your data.